# bcmDPC thread uses CPU more than usual

Tags: juniper

I have an issue with ACX2100, it report high CPU in FPC.

```
juniper@CSG-TBH_KXG_VU_NINH> show chassis fpc 
Aug 12 15:44:10
                     Temp  CPU Utilization (%)   CPU Utilization (%)  Memory    Utilization (%)
Slot State            (C)  Total  Interrupt      1min   5min   15min  DRAM (MB) Heap     Buffer
  0  Online            65     99          3        0      0      0    512        18         44
  1  Online            65     99          3        0      0      0    512        18         44
```

CPU of RE is normal.

```
juniper@CSG-TBH_KXG_VU_NINH> show chassis routing-engine 
Aug 12 15:44:59
Routing Engine status:
    Temperature                 47 degrees C / 116 degrees F
    DRAM                      1536 MB (2048 MB installed)
    Memory utilization          49 percent
    5 sec CPU utilization:
      User                       0 percent
      Background                 0 percent
      Kernel                     2 percent
      Interrupt                  0 percent
      Idle                      98 percent
    1 min CPU utilization:
      User                       3 percent
      Background                 0 percent
      Kernel                     4 percent
      Interrupt                  0 percent
      Idle                      92 percent
```

I checked in shell mode and saw that bcmDPC thread uses CPU more than usual.

```
FFEB(CSG-TBH_KXG_VU_NINH vty)# show sched
Total system uptime 367+16:42:33, (31769309840 ms), 142651053549 thread dispatches
CPU load is 99% (1 second), 99% (5 second)
            99% (10 second), 99% (1 minute)
Total interrupt time 1153266758 (ms)

 CPU       Name      Time(ms)
 72%       Idle      22894234261
 24%    Threads      7721452529
  3%        ISR      1153266758
  3%    Level 1      1152352432
  0%    Level 2      913880
  0%    Level 3      444

Last Long Running Thread Event time 100 ms

 CPU       Name      Time(ms)    Count

 Top Thread:
   pid      = 60
   name     = bcmDPC
   time     = 6567361774 ms
   cpu      = 20%
```

Pls help me on this case.
Thank you.

Comment: Which firmware version is this on?

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the uptime value (>1 year), that ACX is running a firmware prior to 18.3R3 (January 2022) where this issue should be fixed:

> - bcmDPC task is high eventhough Interuppt START_BY_START flag set to 0.[PR1329656](http://prsearch.juniper.net/PR1329656)

https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/information-products/topic-collections/release-notes/18.3/jd0e46.html#jd0e1208

Comment: My OS is Junos: 17.4R2-S9.1. I tried to restart feb and the issue was resolved.

Comment: The PR mentions workaround solution is "Resetting the flag using bcm command.". Can you share me bcm command to do reset?